# Using CROSS APPLY for more than one column

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms, csv, cross-apply

Day #3 with SQL Server.

I am trying to combine 2 columns of delimited data into one output from a Table Valued Function. Here is my data:

[image]

I would like the data to be processed and placed into a table in the following format:

[image]

I am currently *trying* to use this CROSS APPLY TSQL statement, but I don't know what I'm doing.

```
USE [Metrics]
INSERT INTO dbo.tblSplitData(SplitKey, SplitString, SplitValues)
SELECT d.RawKey, c.*, e.*
FROM dbo.tblRawData d
CROSS APPLY dbo.splitstringcomma(d.DelimitedString) c, dbo.splitstringcomma(d.DelimitedValues) e
```

My research on CROSS APPLY has broad context, and I don't understand how it should be applied in this scenario. Do I need a subquery with an additional CROSS APPLY and a join to combine the returns from the two Table Valued Functions?

Here is the split function I was using originally (I can't remember the author to credit them):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[splitstring] ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX), @Delimiter CHAR(1))
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END
```

**Edit & Revised Query**

```
USE [Metrics] 
INSERT INTO dbo.tblSplitData(SplitKey, SplitString, SplitValues)
SELECT s.RawKey, s.SplitString, v.SplitValues
FROM (
SELECT d.RawKey, d.DelimitedString,
 c.item SplitString, c.rn
FROM dbo.tblRawData d
CROSS APPLY dbo.splitstring(d.DelimitedString, ',') c
) s

INNER JOIN

(
SELECT d.RawKey, d.DelimitedValues,
 c.item SplitValues, c.rn
FROM dbo.tblRawData d
CROSS APPLY dbo.splitstring(d.DelimitedValues, ',') c
) v
on s.RawKey = v.RawKey
and s.rn = v.rn;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be easier to answer this if we could see your split string function.  My answer is using a version of my split function that I have.

I would include in your split function a row number that you can use to JOIN the split string and the split values.

Split function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String varchar(MAX), @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(MAX), rn int)       
as       
begin      
    declare @idx int       
    declare @slice varchar(8000)   
    declare @rn int = 1 -- row number that increments with each value in the delimited string

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)   
        else       
            set @slice = @String       

        if(len(@slice)>0)  
            insert into @temptable(Items, rn) values(@slice, @rn)       

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        set @rn = @rn +1

        if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
return 
end;
```

Then if you have multiple columns to split, you could use a query similar to the following:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tblSplitData(SplitKey, SplitString, SplitValues)
select s.rawkey,
  s.splitstring,
  v.splitvalues
from
(
  SELECT d.RawKey, d.delimitedstring, d.delimitedvalues, 
    c.items SplitString, 
    c.rn
  FROM dbo.tblRawData d
  CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(d.DelimitedString, ',') c
) s
inner join
(
  SELECT d.RawKey, d.delimitedstring, d.delimitedvalues, 
    c.items SplitValues, 
    c.rn
  FROM dbo.tblRawData d
  CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(d.DelimitedValues, ',') c
) v
  on s.rawkey = v.rawkey
  and s.delimitedstring = v.delimitedstring
  and s.rn = v.rn;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7487b/4)

This uses two subqueries that generate the list of split values, then they are joined using the row number created by the split function.

Comment: Can't tell you how much I appreciate the help - I'll see if I can't adapt this code right away :)

Comment: Ok - I created a simple version of the query just to test the various returns from the function. It only seems to return two lines; as though it fails to run the last iteration of the Split function... `USE [410_Metrics]
INSERT INTO dbo.tblSplitData(SplitKey, SplitString, RowNumber)
SELECT d.RawKey, c.items, c.rn
FROM dbo.tblRawData d
CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(d.DelimitedString, ',') c`

Comment: @Chris It is difficult to tell since I cannot see what you are using, can you edit the sql fiddle with the exact code and data that you are using?

Comment: Ok, I replaced the SQL (schema?) on the right hand side with the following line: `SELECT d.RawKey, c.items, c.rn
FROM dbo.tblRawData d 
CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(d.DelimitedString, ',') c`. It seems to work just fine in the fiddle... When I run the exact same query in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio, it only returns 2 lines. The fiddle returns all 6... SQL Server returns only John and Sandy. John has a RawKey value of 1, Sandy has a RawKey value of 2.

Comment: @Chris I am not able to reproduce that issue in my SSMS. I am using the Split function from my answer, are you using that function?

Comment: Yes I am... Very odd indeed. I will try copying everything again.

Comment: yeah same result... I wonder if there is something set on my instance of SQL server. I will edit my original post to include the Split function that I was using originally.

Comment: @Chris See this demo with your function altered and it returns the correct result -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f7370/3

Comment: The revised split function works like a champ! I hadn't recognized the appropriate syntax for returns. Would you take a look at my revised query and tell me if there will be any problems with it?

Comment: @Chris I don't see any issues with your query.

Comment: Thanks again! I hope some day I'll have as much knowledge to give as you; can't tell you how much I appreciate the help :)

Comment: @Chris You are welcome! And you will get there, it just takes time! :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on Sql Server 2008 .You can do this without a UDF using XML.

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
( 
    SELECT *
    ,RN= Row_Number() OVER( Partition BY DelemitedString,DelimitedValues,RawKey,TableID ORDER BY TableID)
     FROM 
    (
    SELECT *
    ,DelimitedStringXML = CAST('<d>'+REPLACE(DelemitedString,',','</d><d>')+'</d>' AS XML)
    ,DelimitedValueXML = CAST('<d>'+REPLACE(DelimitedValues,',','</d><d>')+'</d>' AS XML)

     FROM dbo.tblRawData
    ) as t
    Cross Apply
    (
    SELECT y.value('.', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS SplitString FROM DelimitedStringXML.nodes('//d') as  x(y)

    ) as b
)
,CTE2 AS 
(
    SELECT *
    ,RN= Row_Number() OVER( Partition BY DelemitedString,DelimitedValues,RawKey,TableID ORDER BY TableID)
     FROM 
    (
    SELECT *
    ,DelimitedStringXML = CAST('<d>'+REPLACE(DelemitedString,',','</d><d>')+'</d>' AS XML)
    ,DelimitedValueXML = CAST('<d>'+REPLACE(DelimitedValues,',','</d><d>')+'</d>' AS XML)

     FROM dbo.tblRawData
    ) as t
    CROSS APPLY
    (
    SELECT h.value('.', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS SplitValue FROM DelimitedValueXML.nodes('//d') as  g(h)

    ) as c
)


SELECT a.RawKey,a.SplitString,b.SplitValue 
FROM CTE1 as a
INNER JOIN CTE2 as b
    on  a.TableID= b.TableID
    AND a.RN = b.RN
```

Here is [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c58e1/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use cross apply for multiple columns if you put it in brakets and use "AS" twice. It is even aliased so you can use them further in your query.

```
SELECT a.*, b,c
b+c as d
FROM a
CROSS APPLY (Select dbo.Split(d.DelimitedValues, ',') AS b) AS b
CROSS APPLY (Select dbo.Split(d.DelimitedString, ',') AS c) AS c
```